# max number of character in each line in JTextArea based on the font size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I'm having a problem in my java project, we are required to make a GUI which consist `JTextArea`, we have to display the number of lines, words and characters. how can I add `\n` when the user reach the end of line manually?

**PS:** the user can change the font size, or enlarge the GUI.

**NOTE:**

- I used the function

  ```
  textArea.setLineWrap(true);
  textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
  ```

  and for the count of line split (`\n`) when the user make enter my code count the line, but when it reach the last line and automatically add line my code will not count this situation.
- my second try was to figure out the max number of char in each line but when the user change the size of font or the display it will change.

can anyone help me please how can I make a `\n` manually so the split can work correctly without using API ?

Comment: Do you mean manually or do you mean automatically when you say "how can I make a `\n` manually"

Comment: Manually, Thanks for your editing

Comment: Wrapping in a JTextArea will work automatically when you use the two methods you specified in your question. *how can I add \n when the user reach the end of line manually?* You don't want to add "\n" because that becomes a hard coded new line. If you ever change the font, or if you insert text in the middle of a line, the text will no longer wrap properly so you manually force the text to wrap at the new line string.

Comment: then how could i count the line of the wrapped lines ?

Comment: See: [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/)

Comment: Do you need to re-flow the text when the size of window or the size of font is changed? Is the number of columns that JTextArea is strictly specified? Can the number of columns change? Try playing around with JScrollPane and keep the size of JTextArea so that it always contains the required number of columns. Then wrapping the text as you did should work.